# Any good reference for start in Cellular Automata?

Tags: graph-theory, book-recommendation, cellular-automata

The question is as simple as the title. I want to know more about Cellular Automata, and his applications in Chemistry and Biology. I have read that, maybe, there is a relation of the topic with Graph theory, so I'm searching books or any other source where I can read further on Graph theory and Cellular Automata.

---

Thanks in advance
My apologies if I have typos or mistakes in my English.

-If it's useful for the information you want to give me I'm undergraduate student in Mathematics-

Comment: I liked a lot the book "Cellular Automata and Groups" by  Ceccherini-Silberstein, and Coornaert. I only read the chapter about amenable groups but it was extremely clear, I am sure the rest of the book is also clear and lot of elementary results are recalled.
On the other hand, you asked for applications and this book does not contains any applications to my knowledge but maybe it's worth try one or two chapters.